# change width of the fullscreen editor

Tags: editor

I'm using wordpress 4 and want the fullscreen page editor to be just as wide as the text of my page. eg 1024px.

I tried setting #wp-fullscreen-wrap in my css and the dfw_width option but they all seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean the Distraction Free Writing mode. Am I right? Then you changed wrong ID, it's **#wp-content-editor-container** what you want to edit. But every time you hack WordPress core, a kitten dies. So if you like kittens, here is no-offensive solution for you. Put this code into **functions.php** file in your theme:

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'fulleditorwidth', 99 );
function fulleditorwidth() { 
?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wp-content-editor-container { width: 1024px!important }
    </style>

<?php } ?>
```

I recommend to add also **max-width: 100%** for responsive view.

Don’t hack your WordPress core files. If your wordpress will be updated, your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks.. I would never kill kittens, umm hack into the wpp core. This bit of code worked fine when i added your max-width to. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'fulleditorwidth', 99 );

function fulleditorwidth() { 
    echo '<style> #content_ifr { block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 70%!important;}</style>';
    echo '<style> .mce-fullscreen #wp-content-wrap .mce-edit-area, .mce-fullscreen #wp-content-wrap .mce-menubar, .mce-fullscreen #wp-content-wrap .mce-statusbar, .mce-fullscreen #wp-content-wrap .mce-toolbar-grp { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 0!important; width: 60%!important;}</style>';
}
```